# How to Convert hashed string value to integer in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parseint

Here is my code. In productDetails console, [Please click on this link to see console.log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKbS7.png) I'm getting e._id as 5e23683hjhkj value which is ObjectId. but req.params.id as '5e23683hjhkj' (a string value). ParseInt() method is returns only 5. So parseInt method not working here. Please let me know how to convert this req.parmas.id to integer.

app.get('/:id',async(req,res)=>{

```
try{
    const items = await Product.find();
    const productDetails= items.find(e=>console.log(e._id,(req.params.id)))
    res.send(productDetails)
}catch(err){
    console.error(err.message)
    res.status(500).send('Server Error')
}
```

})

Comment: 5e23683hjhkj is not an integer.  Why would you expect parseInt to work?  parseInt will stop at the first non-digit.

Comment: mongo IDs aren't integers - they are ObjectIds, which contain both characters and digits.